# What are the current technologies used for web service discovery? UDDI?

Tags: web-services, soa, discovery, ws-discovery

I'm looking at building a new service discovery platform to allow our customers to provide plugins to our platform. I know that UDDI was the technology "du jour" a while ago, however, in doing some research it appears that UUDI is falling out of favour with people. What are you using for service discovery these days? What would you like to use given the chance?

Answer (score 0):

These days API Gateways are becoming popular choice for Sharing API & related documents along with. As far service discovery is concerned specific vendors have their own implementation as well such as Oracle API Catalog.